# "Active Directory Users and Computers" isn't installed after installing Domain Controller

Tags: domain, users, controller, windows-server-2012

I installed a domain controller and attached it to my domain. It's all worked fine, but "Users and Computers" and "Sites and Services" etc. aren't installed... (all the management tools)

EXTRA INFO:
I installed ADDS with this script:

$user = read-host "Domain\administrator for domain"
$SecurePassword = read-host "Enter domain p​assword" -AsSecureString
$domaincredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList`
 $user, $SecurePassword

Install-WindowsFeature AD-Dom​ain-Services
$domain = "domain.here"​
$sitename = "sitenamehere"

Install-ADDSDomainController -InstallDns:$true -DomainName "$domain" `
-NoRebootOnCompletion:$false -SiteName "$SiteName" -Force -Credential $domaincredentials​

Thanks!

Comment: Please provided specifics.  What OS specifically are you using?

Comment: perhaps this should have been moved to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is load the server manager module again and then install the RSAT tools to go with the AD DS install you have just completed:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Install-WindowsFeature -Name RSAT
```

Easy as that :)

Alternatively, you could have used the -IncludeManagementTools switch in your Install-WindowsFeature command:

```
Install-WindowsFeature AD-Dom​ain-Services $domain = "domain.here"​ $sitename = "sitenamehere" -IncludeManagementTools
```